# JSON ObjectArray with Keys and Values

Tags: javascript, json

I been trying to make the ObjectArray print The key value without have to specify
userData[i].name;
userData[i].lastname;
userData[i].age;

Just puting the key in an array like:

var variables = ["name", "lastname", "age"];[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Podrías intentar algo así:

```
for(var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < variables.length; j++) {
    console.log(userData[i][variables[j]]);
  }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Alan
Gamez
19
Jose
Hernandez
21
Miguel
Aleman
93
```